# Sum of products of incomplete harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

Let $n,k$ be constant integers. What is as tight upper bound on $S$:
$$S_{n,k}=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n-k}\sum_{i_2=1}^{n-i_1}\dots\sum_{i_k=1}^{n-i_{k-1}} \frac{1}{i_1 i_2\dots i_k}$$

It is easy to show that $S\le H(n)^k$ in which $H(n)$ is the harmonic sum. Because every term in $S_{n,k}$ also appears bellow:
$$S_{n,k}<\sum_{i_1=1}^n\frac{1}{i_1}\sum_{i_2=1}^n\frac{1}{i_2}\dots\sum_{i_k=1}^n \frac{1}{i_k} = H(n)^k$$
However, my question is, can a tigher bound be achieved since many terms are not present in $S$? For instance, is thera a multiplicative factor like $\alpha(n,k)<1$ such that $S_{n,k}\le \alpha(n,k) H(n)^k$?

One possible way to estimate or bound $S_{n,k}$ is the following recursive relationship:
$$S_{n,k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} \frac{1}{i} S_{n-i,k-1}$$
and 
$$S_{n,1}=H(n-1)$$
Does this lead to any bound?

Comment: $S_{n,k}<H(n-k)S_{n,k-1}$ And $S_{n,1}=H(n-1)$. Therefore $\prod_{m=1}^k H(n-m)$ should be a bound.

Comment: How does $\prod_{m=1}^k H(n-m)/H(n)^k$ grow with respect to $n$ and $k$? can it be bounded?

Comment: $$S_{n,k}=[x^n]\log^k\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$ can be bounded through the Cauchy integral theorem.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  what's $[x^n]$? and what's $x$ anyway? is that an equality?

Comment: @kvphxga: a symbol for "the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series of"

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio could you elaborate a bit on how Couchy integral theorem can be used to bound the coefficient?

Comment: $$S_{n,k}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \log^k\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x^{n+1}}$$ where the integral is performed along a suitable contour enclosing the origin. If the integrand function can be effectively estimated over such contour, you are done.